Правильный вариант употребления прилагательного – в строке
Правильный вариант употребления прилагательного – в строке:

У мальчика появились более худшие привычки.
Комната низкая для этой мебели.
Стихи удачны по форме и по содержанию.
Самый прекраснейший вид с горы восхищает и захватывает дух.


Правильно:

Стихи удачны по форме и по содержанию.

Исправление

У мальчика появились и более плохие привычки.

Комната низка для этой мебели.

Прекрасный вид с горы восхищает и захватывает дух.


Теория
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/prilagatelnoe/prevoshodnaya-stepen.html
https://studfile.net/preview/1700657/page:91/
